# Панель управления для Landing Page?

Tags: php, html, css

Привет. Есть ли какой-то движок для управлени лэндингами? Вижу, что на фрилансе заказчики зачастую хотят не статичную страничку, а управляемый лэндинг, чтобы где-то поставить свою картинку, где-то изменить адрес или номер телефона, где-то изменить тексты.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

textolite.ru - самое простое, что есть. Установка - перетаскиваешь папку через FTP в корень лэндинга к index.html и вуаля, сделано :)

Comment: А вот это интересная штука! Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Самый оптимальный вариант - `CMS`.

Их очень много: 
[WordPress](https://ru.wordpress.com/) - идеально подойдет для лендинга, блога, отличный вариант для интернет-магазина
[Joomla](http://joomla.ru/) - отличное распределение ролей, явно не для лендинга, но никто ведь не запрещает =)
Есть ещё и `OpenCart` и `Magento` и `Drupal` и куча менее известных

Comment: WP изначально создавался, как движок для блогов, а потом под него наклепали кучу скриптов, которые дико тормозят работу WP даже на VPS. А Joomla - это вообще непонятно для чего. То ли для каких-то многостраничных сайтов, то ли для интернет-магазинов. С OpenCart я вообще работать не хочу. У разработчиков этого чуда .htaccess головного мозга. В общем, не для одностраничных сайтов это всё.

Comment: А для одностраничника много плагинов, скриптов, и пр. не нужно. Джумла - явно не для одностраничных сайтов, просто как пример  системы управления контентом. А вот ВП подойдет на ура, если дело касается простого как 5 пальцев лендинга(контактная форма+калькулятор+максимум слайдер/галерея)